# Асинхронная обработка запросов ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, асинхронность

Есть страница, которую открыл первый пользователь. Для неё ответ на запрос сервер отдаёт через 10 секунд.

В это время другой пользователь хочет обратиться к другой странице. Здесь сервер отработает  1 секунду.

В то время, когда сервер "думает" над первой страницей, второму пользователю ждать (10+1=11 секунд).

Что сделать, чтобы сервер смог ответить на запрос второго пользователя, работая в это же время над первым запросом? Понятно, что можно сделать Async="true" на странице aspx и обрабатывать запрос, обернув их в специальные методы.

А можно сделать так, чтобы для каждого запроса создавался свой трэд (поток, нить), прописав, например, это в config-файле? То есть "одним махом"?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET, как и любой другой сервер, выполняет запросы от разных пользователей параллельно.

Единственное, что может выстраивать запросы в настолько жесткую очередь - это использование Session State. Если

- включить использование сессии
- открыть таб в браузере - зайти на сайт, получив сессионную куку
- открыть второй таб в браузере, и мерять, предполагая что "разные табы/окна - разные пользователи"

то наблюдаемый результат будет точно таким же, как описан в вопросе - потому что браузер будет использовать общую сессионную куку в каждом табе или окне. ASP.NET сочтет это запросами в рамках одной сессии, и будет выполнять их строго последовательно.

Единственный способ избежать такого неочевидного и тормозного поведения - [не использовать сессии, ни прямо, ни в виде ASP.NET MVC TempData](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424111/177221).