# Использование механизма сессий для хранения временных данных

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

В разрабатываемом приложении осуществляется тестирование пользователей. Естественно во время теста возникла необходимость сохранять промежуточные итоги: Количество ошибок, количество правильных ответов и пр. В начале планировалось проводить тест почти полностью на клиенте, но потом возникли сложности с тем чтобы защититься от подделки данных и решено было перенести все на сервер. Теперь возник вопрос:
Разумно ли и безопасно хранить текущие данные в сессии или лучше добавлять их в БД?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Безопасно. Сессия полностью хранится на серверной стороне. Но вот разумно ли - зависит от мнения. Мое мнение:

## НИ В КОЕМ СЛУЧАЕ НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ СТАНДАРТНЫЙ МЕХАНИЗМ СЕССИЙ В ASP.NET

...и опирающийся на него же механизм TempData. Практически ни к коем случае, кроме редких исключений, описанных в конце ответа.

Несмотря на всю простоту использования, у механизма сессий есть огромное количество потенциальных проблем.

### Проблемы из-за самого наличия сессионной куки

Запросы с общей сессионной кукой всегда выполняются последовательно. ASP.NET тупо не может выполнить два запроса из одной сессии одновременно. Он ставит их в очередь и вызывает по одному. Это дико бьет по производительности. Если пользователь запустил что-то долгое (репорт на минуту) на сайте в одном табе - то в другом табе сайт у него тупо будет висеть. Это написано мелким шрифтом в [MSDN на странице, посвященной сессиям](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx), но кто ж читает MSDN.

Это частично решается явным отключением сессии для всех страниц и всех контроллеров по умолчанию, и выборочным включением ее для отдельных действий, в случае необходимости.

### Проблемы со стандартным способом хранения - InProc:

- Стандартный механизм хранения сессий ненадежен. Он будет терять данные при ресайкле приложения - при неактивности, при большой нагрузке, при заливке новой версии.
- Стандартный механизм хранения сессий не масштабируется. Он просто не работает в случае двух серверов. Или одного сервера и двух рабочих процессов. Или одного сервера, одного рабочего процесса при включенном Overlapping Recycling.

### Проблемы с хранением сессии в SQL Server:

- В зависимости от объема хранимых данных - это может быть медленно. SQL Server не приспособлен к хранению больших объемов данных прямо в таблице. Он делает это меееедлееенно.
- Проблема "в один момент времени - один запрос" при этом выходит на новый уровень. Теперь каждый запрос, использующий сессию, ставит на нее блокировку. Вызовом SQL. А потом снимает ее. Вызовом SQL. Что дает вам два запроса к базе на ровном месте, даже если контроллер не лезет в сессию.
- В зависимости от провайдера, можно напороться еще и на проблему в очисткой сессий, например, рекомендованные (с) System.Web.Providers (r), при обработке каждого запроса лезут в базу еще и для того, чтобы почистить старые сессии. *Каждого запроса, Карл!*

### Что использовать вместо сессий

В живом - открытом в интернет, или просто доступном большому количеству пользователей приложении альтернатив в смысле "правильных замен сессии" нет.

Сама по себе необходимость организовать что-то вроде сессии - это прямой и однозначный признак просчета в архитектуре. Использование сессий или любого их подобия практически означает невозможность распределенного деплоя. Убирает возможность эффективно использовать кэш. Сессии - это **всегда** bottleneck.  Если они нужны - значит вы делаете что-то неправильно.

Например, в случае с приложением для тестирования стоит хранить на клиенте данные ответы. Это не исключает хранения промежуточных итогов, но окончательный итог надо подсчитывать на сервере, и только с использованием самих ответов, а не промежуточных итогов. Промежуточные итоги можно использовать для валидации - если вдруг что-то разошлось - значит клиент *пытался* читерить.

### С другой стороны

если у вас intranet-приложение, которым пользуются, например, студенты, при прохождении теста, то одного сервера с одним рабочим процессом и настроенным хранением сессии в ASP.NET State Server вам хватит заглаза. От вас потребуется только [поставить стандартный сервер через вызовом `aspnet_state.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx), прописать режим `StateServer` в конфиге и отметить все хранимые объекты как сериализуемые.

Это в разы проще, чем ручная организация хранения сложных временных объектов в базе.

Только режим хранения InProc не используйте - он не предназначен для использования в хоть насколько-то рабочем окружении.

Comment: Вы не написали, как делать *правильно*. :)

Comment: @Discord дописал.

Comment: Но это же всё равно "СТАНДАРТНЫЙ МЕХАНИЗМ СЕССИЙ В ASP.NET", который "НИ В КОЕМ СЛУЧАЕ НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ". Что использовать-то?

Comment: @Discord в конце ответа расписано к каком случае его стоит использовать. могу добавить сноску в начале.

Comment: Я понял из текста, когда и как его следует использовать. Но у вас самая заметная надпись — это что его использовать не стоит. Если так, то имеет смысл предложить альтернативы.

Comment: @Discord. в живом (открытом в интернет, или просто доступном большому количеству пользователей) альтернатив в смысле "правильных замен сессии" нет. Сама по себе необходимость организовать что-то вроде сессий - это уже просчет в архитектуре. Это практически означает невозможность распределенного деплоя. Убирает возможность эффективно использовать кэш. Сессии (или любое их подобие) - это всегда bottleneck. Если они нужны - значит вы делаете что-то неправильно :(

Comment: Этот текст достоен включения в ответ. ;) Возможно, даже с дополнениями, как обходить необходимость в сессиях.

Comment: @Discord добавил.

Comment: Во, теперь отлично!