# Приложение для тестирование знаний без использования сессий

Tags: алгоритм, asp.net-mvc

Разрабатываю web-приложение для тестирования знаний. Ответ на вопрос посредством ajax отправляется серверу. В свою очередь сервер решает, насколько вопрос верен и возвращает результат клиенту, предоставляя затем новый вопрос.

При таком алгоритме возникает потребность в хранении промежуточного результата. Возможно ли усовершенствовать алгоритм таким образом, чтобы такая потребность не возникала? Данные на клиенте хранить небезопасно, при пересылке серверу они могут быть подделаны, а содержать в сессии - неразумно.

Comment: присылайте все ответы только в конце, или подписывайте свои ответы типа: `yes, md5('yes',serverkey, questionId);`

Comment: есть правда одна проблемка... если на сервере ничего не хранить, то тестируемый может спросить ajax хоть тыщу раз и узнать правильный ответ и его контрольную сумму. (я правда не знаю, зачем вообще сообщать клиенту о том правильный это был ответ или нет)

Comment: А что плохого в сессиях? Имхо эта работа именно для них.

Comment: @Darth конкретно в asp.net в сессиях [много плохого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424104/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: Приложение создается не просто как тест знаний, а как обучающее, поэтому нужно указывать, что ответ не верен и показывать правильный, однако на ряду с этим используется рейтинговая система и потому подделки крайне не желательны.

Answer (score 1):

Появилась идея поступить следующим образом: в том случае если ответ верен возвращать id верного ответа и хранить его на клиенте, а в конце отсылать всю эту информацию серверу.

Answer (score 0):

У вас достаточно структурированные данные. Храните в базе. Вам ведь все равно надо будет где-то сохранить результат прохождения теста - вот пусть он у вас и образуется по мере прохождения.

Хранение сведется просто к записи очередного ответа, и проверке что на тот же вопрос еще не был дан ответ.