# Альтернатива ViewState

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

В одном из онлайн-уроков, встретил мнение, что ViewState крайне тяжеловестная и при работе на серьезных проектах затормаживает сайты в 10+ раз.

Справедливо ли это мнение? Если да, то какие более быстрые альтернативы целесообразно использовать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мнение полностью справедливо. Но есть проблема - вся логика работы ASP.NET WebForms завязана на этот самый ViewState.

WebForms пропихивает абстракцию "долгоживущего объекта-страницы, на котором есть контролы с состоянием и эвентами" - и это состояние надо где-то хранить.

От ViewState без перехода на MVC вы не избавитесь. Можно попытаться минимизировать его  - отключить у тех контролов, которые не должны переживать постбек - но это достаточно тяжело сделать, не понимая полностью механизи работы ViewState. Настолько, что из-за постоянных глюков приложений, вызванных неудачными попытками разработчиков отключить ViewState, MS вынесла критическую часть его в отдельный неотключабельный ControlState.

Можно попробовать хранить ViewState не в теле страницы, а где-то еще:

- в сессии - через [`SessionPageStatePersister`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.sessionpagestatepersister.aspx). Но сессия сама по себе - [чистейшее зло](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424111/177221) (еще злее вьюстейта и вебформ).
- в NoSQL - например, в MongoDB.
- в кэше - например, в Redis.

Под последние два также можно найти готовые адаптеры (или достаточно быстро набросать их самому). Да, идея запихивать несколько мегабайт бинарных данных в Mongo может показаться странной, но альтернатива - гонять те же данные в скрытом поле на странице при каждом запросе от браузера.

---

Но единственный нормальный способ решить проблему с ViewState - не использовать WebForms.

Comment: Уточнение: насколько разумно использовать MongoDB только как промежуточную базу данных для хранения ViewState значений, а весь основной код хранить в MSSQL? (по условиям задачи от MSSQL нельзя отказаться)

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron вполне разумно. у меня на проекте одно время именно так и было сделано - мы держали MongoDB только под ViewState (с проставлением авточистки - expireAfterSeconds для записей вьюстейта)

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю всех тонкостей ViewState и ASP.NET WebForms, поэтому ниже изложенное субъективно и не стоит считать за чистую правду.

Да, viewstate хранит свойства контролов со всей страницы и при клиент-серверном взаимодействии всегда отправляет их всей кучей. В итоге, даже если Вы захотите обновить какое-то одно маленькое значение, в запросах будут участвовать все свойства со страницы. С точки зрения HTTP это крайне нецелесообразное решение и это та плата, которую вы платите за привычную форму работы с WebForms декстопными приложениями.

Решение - минимизировать количество незначительных запросов к серверу.

Альтернативы - использовать ASP.NET MVC, там нет viewstate и используются чистые HTTP запросы.

Можно еще хабр почитать: http://habrahabr.ru/post/119537/