# Как вызвать метод aspx страницы из web service

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть web service, в процессе его работы мне необходимо получить данные метода который находится на aspx странице. Возможно это как нибудь сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Я сегодня задался [сходным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458489/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-viewstate) вопросом. Как я понимаю товарищ @PashaPash советует использовать MongoDB либо NoSQL аналог.