# Помогите разобраться в ошибке An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь сделать оформление заказа но возникает такая ошибка

```
Ошибка источника: 


Строка 63: if (order.ID_ORDER_BOOK == 0) 
Строка 64: { 
Строка 65: order = context.nameorder.Add(order); 
Строка 66: 
Строка 67: foreach (OrderLine line in order.OrderLines)
```

Так пытаюсь сохранить данные заказа в бд.

```
  public void SaveOrder(order_book order)
    {
        if (order.ID_ORDER_BOOK == 0)
        {
            order = context.nameorder.Add(order);

            foreach (OrderLine line in order.OrderLines)
            {
                context.Entry(line.book).State
                    = EntityState.Modified;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            order_book dbOrder = context.nameorder.Find(order.ID_ORDER_BOOK);
            if (dbOrder != null)
            {
                dbOrder.DATE_DELIVERY = order.DATE_DELIVERY;
                dbOrder.DATE_ISSUE = order.DATE_ISSUE;
                dbOrder.CLIENT_ID = order.CLIENT_ID;
                dbOrder.EMPLOYEE_ID = order.EMPLOYEE_ID;

            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Классы

```
 public class book
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_BOOK { get; set; }
    public string NAME_BOOK { get; set; }
    public int? AUTHOR_ID { get; set; }
    public int PUBLISHING_HOUSE_ID { get; set; }
    public string YEAR_PUB { get; set; }
    public int CATEGORY_ID { get; set; }
    public int ISBN { get; set; }
    public int ISSN { get; set; }
    public int STATUS_ID { get; set; }
    public int STATE_ID { get; set; }
    public int LOCATION_ID { get; set; }
    public int GENRE_ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AUTHOR_ID")]
    public virtual author_books author_book { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GENRE_ID")]
    public virtual genre_book genre_book { get; set; }
    public virtual List<order_book> order_book { get; set; }
 public class order_book
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_ORDER_BOOK { get; set; }
    public int? CLIENT_ID { get; set; }
    public int? EMPLOYEE_ID { get; set; }
    public string DATE_ISSUE { get; set; }
    public string DATE_DELIVERY { get; set; }
    public int? BOOK_ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BOOK_ID")]
    public virtual book book { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EMPLOYEE_ID")]
    public virtual employee employee { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CLIENT_ID")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }

  public class OrderLine
{
    public int OrderLineId { get; set; }
    public order_book Order { get; set; }
    public book book { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

веб форма

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Checkout.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="Library.Pages.Checkout"
MasterPageFile="~/Pages/Lib.Master" %>
```

```
    <div id="checkoutForm" class="checkout" runat="server">
        <h2>Оформить заказ</h2>
        Пожалуйста, введите свои данные, и мы отправим Ваш товар прямо сейчас!

    <div id="errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
        <ul>
            <li style="display:none"></li>
        </ul>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
    </div>

        <h3></h3>
        <div>
            <label for="DATE_DELIVERY">D</label>
            <input id="DATE_DELIVERY" name="DATE_DELIVERY" runat="server" />
        </div>

        <h3></h3>
        <div>
            <label for="DATE_ISSUE">D</label>
            <input id="DATE_ISSUE" name="DATE_ISSUE" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="CLIENT_ID">C</label>
            <input id="CLIENT_ID" name="CLIENT_ID" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="EMPLOYEE_ID">E</label>
            <input id="EMPLOYEE_ID" name="EMPLOYEE_ID" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <h3>Детали заказа</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" id="giftwrap" name="giftwrap" value="true" />
        Использовать подарочную упаковку?

    <p class="actionButtons">
        <button class="actionButtons" type="submit">Обработать заказ</button>
    </p>


    </div>
    <div id="checkoutMessage" runat="server">
        <h2>Спасибо!</h2>
       Мы постараемся максимально быстро отправить ваш заказ   
    </div>
</div>
```

И code-behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Library.Models;
using Library.Models.Repository;
using Library.Pages.Helpers;
using System.Web.ModelBinding;

 namespace Library.Pages
 {
    public partial class Checkout : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkoutForm.Visible = true;
        checkoutMessage.Visible = false;

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            order_book myOrder = new order_book();
            if (TryUpdateModel(myOrder,
               new FormValueProvider(ModelBindingExecutionContext)))
            {

                myOrder.OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>();

                Cart myCart = SessionHelper.GetCart(Session);

                foreach (CartLine line in myCart.Lines)
                {
                    myOrder.OrderLines.Add(new OrderLine
                    {
                        Order = myOrder,
                        book = line.book,
                        Quantity = line.Quantity
                    });
                }

                new Repository().SaveOrder(myOrder);
                myCart.Clear();

                checkoutForm.Visible = false;
                checkoutMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: посмотрите [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker)

Comment: @Grundy да, тут явно где-то запрятан второй контекст. только непонятно, где именно.

Comment: @Grundy нашел! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый контекст в EF отслеживает изменения загруженных через него объектов - чтобы сохранить из при вызове `SaveChanges()`. Поэтому объект не может быть привязан к двум контекстам одновременно - иначе непонятно, что с ним и со связанными с ними объектами из контекста `context1` должно произойти при вызове `context2.SaveChanges()`.

Что происходит у вас:

- Вы в какой-то момент загружаете объект `book` из контекста 1. Закидываете его в сессию. Сессия у вас в InProc, так что хранится оригинальный объект, а не его сериализованное представление.
- При создании заказа вы создаете новый контекст 2. Создаете Order, добавляете в него OrderLine, который ссылается на book.
- Пытаетесь привязать order к контексту 2. Это приводит к привязке OrderLine и book к контексту 2. А book уже привязан к context1. Эксепшн.

Как починить (чем ниже - тем лучше вариант):

- не хранить привязанные к контексту объекты в сессии. Отвязыват их при выходе за границы BL (`context.Books.Detach(someBook)`). Привязывать заново (Attach) при создании заказа.
- или: не хранить сущности в сессии вообще! У вас book лежит в базе. Нет никакого смысла хранить ее еще и в сессии.
- или: [не использовать сессии вообще. Они зло.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424111/177221) Например, в вашем сетапе корзина будет теряться при перезапуске приложения. В вашем случае - стоит использовать куки для хранения id книг в корзине.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно использовать метод `AsNoTracking` при загрузке нужного вам объекта.
Тогда строка:

```
order_book dbOrder = context.nameorder.Find(order.ID_ORDER_BOOK);
```

выглядела бы так:

```
order_book dbOrder = context.nameorder.AsNoTracking().Find(order.ID_ORDER_BOOK);
```

При загрузке объекта таким способом, изменения этого объекта не будут отслеживаться в EF.