# ASP.NET MVC 4. Как отобразить пользователям разную функциональность + в зависимости от requet'a на одной View?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть метод `Index`, контроллера `NewsController`. Он показывает `View` с коллекцией новостей.

Причем, если это был `Request` из кабинета *Пользователя*, то показываются новости, которые создал этот пользователь и не важно какая у него роль, важно только, что этот запрос был сделан из кабинета *Пользователя*. Если `Request` делается из кабинета *Администратора*, на этот же метод `Index`, то показывает новости всех пользователей и рендерит эту же `View`, но с расширенным функционалом, и тогда уже вступают в игру роли. Если *Admin*, то доп. кнопки.

Вопрос: как лучше это сделать?

У меня есть несколько вариантов, но какой выбрать я не знаю:

1. На основе Routes:

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Admin News",
       url: "Admin/News",
       defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Index" }
   );

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Profile News",
       url: "Profile/News",
       defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Index" }
   );
   ```

Соответственно уже в методе контроллера проверять с какого *URL* сделан был `Request` и отталкиваясь от этих данных заниматься настройкой функциональности `View`.

2. Передавать дополнительный параметр в метод `Index` контроллера `News`:

   ```
   public ActionResult Index(bool IsAdminCabinet, ... ) {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Или же добавить еще два метода: `News` в контроллерах `Profile` и `Admin`:

   ```
   public class ProfileController : Controller {
       public ActionResult News() {
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "News");
       }
   }
   public class AdminController : Controller {
       public ActionResult News() {
           TempData["IsAdminCabinet"] = true;
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "News");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: А почему вы делаете редирект, вместо того, чтобы просто выбрать доступные пользователю новости и отобразить?

Comment: и, ктста - TempData - это на самом деле сессия. чисто зло, будет тормозить и немасштабироваться - не используйте ее - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424111/177221

Comment: Редерект делается, потому что в разных частях приложения мы должны получить разные данные для одного View, ну и соответственно отрендерить его с нужными нам в данный момент данными и функционалом. По поводу TempData не знал, спасибо.

Comment: вы можете просто указать имя View при возврате ViewResult, и отрендерить один и тот же вид из двух разных действий.

Comment: Хмм, точно ведь, можно попробовать. А как насчет того, что мне нужно в пером случае рендерить View c функционалом для админа, а во втором рендерить View с функционалом пользователя, но он так же может являться админом? В одном из методов можно использовать VIewBag.IsAdmin, чтобы попытаться настроить View? Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: А как насчет 1 варианта на Routes?

Comment: смотрите ответ :) вариант хороший - но проверять надо не url (или по крайней мере не только URL), в первую очередь наличие прав админа у текущего пользователя. пришедшему с клиента url вообще верить нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Результат не должен зависеть от данных, пришедших от клиента - иначе обычный пользователь допишет `?IsAdminCabinet=true` и будет скандал.

Вы же точно знаете текущего пользователя на сервере. Так, если предположить что модель у модель одинаковая, у вас два варианта:

Если View очень похожи - отличаются наличием кнопок - использовать один View:

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult News()
    {
        var model = new NewsModel();
        model.News = GetRegularUserNews();
        model.ShowAdminControls = false;
        return new View("News", model);
    }
}

public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [AdminOnly]
    public ActionResult News()
    {
        var model = new NewsModel();
        model.News = GetAllNews();
        model.ShowAdminControls = true;
        return new View("News", model);
    }
}
```

положить один вид News.cshtml в Shared, спрятать кнопки по `@model.ShowAdminControls`.

Если код выборки (построения модели) общий и для пользователей и для админов - то можно оставить один контроллер и одно действие. Роуты по нему - на ваше усмотрение, они влияют только на видимый url в адресной строке браузера.

```
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult News()
    {
        var model = new NewsModel();
        model.News = GetNewsVisibleForCurrentUser();
        model.ShowAdminControls = CurrentUser.IsAdmin;
        return new View("News", model);
    }
}
```

---

Если виды действительно разные - то

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult News()
    {
        var model = new NewsModel();
        model.News = GetRegularUserNews();
        return new View("News", model);
    }
}

public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [AdminOnly]
    public ActionResult News()
    {
        var model = new NewsModel();
        model.News = GetAllNews();
        return new View("News", model);
    }
}
```

Положить два *разных* View в соответствующие папки. Общий html для строчки новостей рендерить через `RenderPartial`.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Answer (score 0):

Для расширенного функционала можно создать разные partial view.
Во View добавить проверку условия и вызов, например, такой

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Admin.cshtml", model)
```

Comment: Будет лишнее дублирование, усложнится поддержка, как мне кажется.

Comment: у вас общее для всех ролей должно находиться во View, а специфика выносится в отдельные partial'ы. т.е. дублирования не будет. просто во View будет if/switch который выбирает нужный partial.