# Пагинация (paging) asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paging

Как грамотно реализовывается пагинация в asp mvc? Дела следующим образом.
Есть некий объект, который отображается на странице

```
 public class Main
 {
     string Akt_Name { get; set; }
     [Key]
     public string Reg_Num { get; set; }
 }
```

Список данных объектов я получаю в результате поиска в БД. Ну а далее использую `PagedList.MVC`

```
List<Main> lst = new List<Main>(); - объявляю как глобальный.
return PartialView(lst.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Код представления:

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model PagedList.IPagedList<LocalEtalon_mvc.Models.Main>
@using WebApp.Models;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@foreach (Main item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <span class="S_regnum">@item.Reg_Num</span> <span class="S_aktname">@item.Akt_Name</span>
        <br />
        <a id="aRegnum_@item.Reg_Num" class="Aktcard" href="#">карта</a> <a id="tRegnum_@item.Reg_Num" class="Akttext" href="#">текст</a>
    </li>
}
Страница @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) из @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("changePage", new { page }))

<script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>
```

И вроде все работает, но только до смены страницы. lst зануляется и на этом все. Что я делаю не так? Какие есть варианты хранения lst? Не уже ли надо каждый раз искать в БД и возвращать список найденного?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lst не переживает переходы между страницами - MVC создает новый экземпляр класса контроллера на каждый запрос. Более того - при реальном развертывании приложений обычно используют несколько серверов, и запрос за второй страницей может дойти на другой физический сервер.

Вам стоит заново выбирать данные из базы каждый раз. Желательно также при этом вызывать `ToPagedList` у оригинального `IQueryable`, а не у всего списка объектов, выбранного в память - тогда из базы будет загружена только конкретная страница.

Есть варианты с хранением lst

- В кэше - доступен через `HttpContext.Cache`, общий для всех пользователей + стоит заранее решить как инвалидировать его при изменении списка.
- В сессии ([не советую, вызывает слишком много проблем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424111/177221)).

Но в небольшом приложении все-таки проще заново выбрать данные из базы.

Comment: `Вам стоит заново выбирать данные из базы каждый раз. Желательно также при этом вызывать ToPagedList у оригинального IQueryable, а не у всего списка объектов, выбранного в память - тогда из базы будет загружена только конкретная страница.` А не могли бы чуть подробнее? Или ссылку. Вебом занимаюсь не долго, опыта мало. А вот приложение должно работать с большим объемом информации (плюс сложность запросов к БД).

Comment: @Rans скорее всего вы сейчас делаете запрос через что-то вроде EF, потом вызываете у него `ToList()` и складываете результат в lst. Тем самым вы выбираете из базы все объекты. Вместо этого надо убрать вызов `ToList()`, и вызывать `ToPagedList()` непосредственно у вашего запроса к базе. Подробнее тяжело сказать, не видя вашего кода :(

Comment: @Rans почитайте про LINQ и про то, в какой момент при работе через него выполняется запрос к базе.

Comment: Вы полностью правы, если в целом, то как раз это у меня и происходит. Про LINQ еще раз прочитаю. Остается у меня еще один вопрос. По сути, у меня есть форма поиска и результаты поиска я как раз и пытаюсь отобразить. Т.е. при сабмите, некий метод осуществляет поиск по базе и формирует список. А как же быть в таком случае при клике по номеру страницы? Откуда собрать инфу по критериям поиска? Форма на странице есть (делал страницу через BS Tab), но ведь до того что туда ввели уже не добраться(

Comment: @Rans добавляйте критерии поиска в модель, и на на view делайте их частью ссылки - передавайте параметрами в `Url.Action("changePage", new { page }`.

Comment: С `ToPagedLIst()` получилось все четко, спасибо. А вот с моделькой никак( Все никак не пойму. `@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("doSearch", "home", new { s = new Main(), page }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "UL_resultslist" }))`. Понятно что новый объект создает. А как старый получить? Дело в том что основная разметка у меня в Layout. Index у меня `PartialView` и только сама форма поиска. И Ajax'ом получаю результаты. т.е. список вместе в `@Html.PagedListPager` у меня в другом `PartialView`