# Почему запросы в ASP.NET не выполняются параллельно?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, asp.net, распараллеливание

В ASP .NET (C#) проекте столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда обрабатывается один запрос (там идет достаточно интенсивная и многопоточная работа с БД) я не могу открыть параллельно другую страницу, т.е. она висит, пока не закончит выполнятся предыдущая. От чего такое может быть, как можно решить проблему или хотя бы в каком направлении копать?

Comment: Сессии (Session State) используете?

Comment: Если используете - то https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424111/177221

Comment: Думаю, что из-за блокировки таблицы бд.

Comment: на самом деле стоит остановить проект в момент "зависания" и посмотреть, на чем стоят другие потоки. если на вызовах базы - значит блокировки DB. если висят страницы именно в этом браузере, а страницы в анонимном режиме открываются - значит из-за сессии

Comment: PashaPash, попробую остановить, а насчет сессий, скорее всего нет, но тоже проверю, спасибо!

Comment: @PashaPash♦ - Все таки дело оказалось в сессиях! Спасибо за помощь, буду разбираться дальше!