# Как лучше хранить сессию пользователя, чтобы уберечь данные от похищения?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день! Давно создаю проекты, используя ASP.NET + MVC. Для хранения пользовательских данных текущей сессии всегда использовал Session. Но близится очень важный проект, где безопасность должна быть на очень высоком уровне. Так что мой вопрос: где и в каком виде лучше хранить данные текущей пользовательской сессии, дабы обезопасить их от похищения/изменения?

Comment: а какие у вас еще варианты собственно?

Comment: @teran Собственно, никаких. Потому и спрашиваю

Comment: А каким образом можно украсть данные с коллекции Session? Только имея доступ к процессу IIS. А если есть доступ к процессу, то сессию в любом случае украдут, что бы вы не делали с ней.

Comment: @Zergatul То есть не существует методов для кражи данных из Session, не имея доступа к самой машине?

Comment: @Zergatul Ведь доступ к сессии идёт по 120-битовому ключу. Есть же мизерная вероятность, что злоумышленник сможет получить данные сессии другого человека + так как сессии всех активных пользователей хранятся в памяти работающей машины, это может привести к серьёзным проблемам, когда начнётся многотысячный приток пользователей

Comment: @Kir_Antipov если вы выполняете только managed-код в процессе IIS, то способа нет. Разве что какая-то неизвестная никому уязвимость. Но таких серьезных уязвимостей в .NET никогда не было.

Comment: @Zergatul это хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Вы когда нибудь видели, что бы какой-то ресурс взламали через сессии? Нет, такого никто не делает. Обычно получают доступ к базе данных или к файловой системе. Лучше проверить эти места в коде, чем пытаться защитить сессию.

Comment: На всякий случай - раз используете сессии, вы должны знать об их ограничениях - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424111/177221, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/735773/177221

Comment: И да, не забывайте что сессия - это сессия браузера, а не пользователя. Если у вас в приложении есть аутентификация, то при залогиненного пользователя сессию нужно очищать, иначе он увидит чужие данные

Comment: @PashaPash  Так, понятно. Про сессии забываем и делаем что-то своё хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov ну зачем сразу забывать :). Если у вас один сервер + аккуратно отключена сессия для тех запросов, где она не нужна, или если у вас asp.net core + redis в качестве хранилища сессии - то все ок. Просто лучше знать об ограничениях заранее, до того как все пойдет плохо.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov на всякий случай - в asp.net core сессия неблокирующая: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x#configuring-session, так что если у вас core - то все хорошо (за исключением того, то написано по ссылке в разделе "Do not store sensitive data in session.")

Comment: @PashaPash Так-так. А не подскажете, она работает как и стандартная сессия Asp.Net (в том плане, что у каждого человека своя сессия), или же это некая общая коллекция? Прошу прощения за скорее всего глупый вопрос, но с Asp.Net Core раньше никогда не работал

Comment: @Kir_Antipov так же, как стандартная сессия (т.е. устанавливается не-persistent cookie, которая не переживает рестарт браузера. для каждой куки на сервере заводится своя коллекция). Просто реализация в asp.net core чуть более правильная.

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо вам огромное! Очень помогли!