# Отследить время последнего запроса пользователя к сайту, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Стоит задача присылать администратору информацию о зарегистрированных пользователях, которые уже месяц не заходили в приложение. Для этого нужно сохранять в базе данных время последнего отправленного авторизованным пользователем запроса. Как ловить такие запросы для добавления нового времени в бд? (не прописывая для этого логику в каждом контроллере)

Comment: `которые уже месяц не заходили в приложение` - так пишите это при входе в приложение.

Comment: @tym32167, пользователь может месяцами не авторизоваться, но пользоваться приложением

Comment: Сессия тоже месяцами висит?

Comment: @tym32167 сессия в asp.net не имеет никакого отношения ко входу в приложение. Механизм сессий вообще включается только после явного обращения к нему. Т.е. да,  пользователь может быть активен, оставаться в приложении месяцами, не логинясь притом не разу и не получив при этом ни одну сессию.

Comment: @PashaPash Автору надо определять неактивных юзеров, которые не были залогинены и не заходили на сервер. Сессия с этим не справится? В каких случаях при заходе и аутентицикации юзера сессия не создастся?

Comment: @tym32167 В каких случаях при заходе и аутентицикации юзера сессия не создастся? - вообще в любых :) в asp.net - сессия - это "браузерная сессия". она не имеет **вообще никакого** отношения к аутентификации и авториации. Сессия создается при обращении к Session, и привязывается к текущей браузерной сессии за счет неперсистентной куки. Нет в коде обращения к Session - нет сессии. Есть обращение к Session, но вообще нет аутентификации и авторизации - сессия все равно есть.

Comment: @tym32167 можете провести эксперимент - создать пустое mvc приложение, поставить брекпойнты на Session_Start/Session_End, и посмотреть в какие моменты они вызываются - увидите, что никакого отношения аутентификации они не имеют.

Comment: @PashaPash то, что аутенификация не связана с сессией я в курсе, я просто говорю о варианте, когда бекенд пишет дату/время посещения при каждом запросе в сессию если юзер аутентифицирован (и в БД при создании/закрытии сессии, если юзер аутентифицирован) - мне кажется такое может помочь решить проблему, разве нет?

Comment: @tym32167 поможет, но при этом вы получите блокировку одновременных запросов (из-за записи в сессию) + необходимость сессию сериализовать (в базу?) или настраивать affinity - вобщем, гораздо проще писать в базу на каждом запросе напрямую, чем по схеме "писать в сессию (а сессию - в/из базы на каждом запросе), а в конце сессии - в базу"

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо за разъяснение по поводу опасности работы сессии. Проект с которым я работаю очень старый, прошел через не одного поколений джунов и писался с особой жестокостью. Сессии в нем используются повсюду, поэтому использовать событие старта сессии для моей задачи подходит. Но чисто на будущее, есть ли другие способы выявить начало работы пользователя с приложением?

Comment: @mirypoko если честно - на моем проекте долго пытались сделать нормальный трекинг всяких заходил/не заходил/совершал какие-то действия. в конце концов оказалось что проще прикрутить сторонний сервис (intercom.io) и не изобретать свой велосипед :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global.asax добавьте методы по обработке сессий. Как вариант, но есть ограничения. Подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813462/session-end-does-not-fire) (это не последний запрос, но если вычесть время жизни сессии, то примерно получится время с последнего запроса)

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //обработка начала сессии
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)//если надо понять залогинен ли
        {
        }
}

protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //обработка конца сессии
}
```

Comment: Я думаю для решения моей задачи подойдет время последнего старта сесии. Спасибо большое

Comment: Эти методы страбатывают только при использовании механизма сессий (которым вообще в asp.net лучше не пользоваться)

Comment: @PashaPash почему?

Comment: @tym32167 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424104/

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, полезно было почитать