# asp.net web api приложение ведет себя как однопоточное

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, asp.net-web-api, asp

Странное поведение asp.net web api приложения. При отправке двух  запросов приложение выполняет их последовательно,это отчетливо видно под отладкой. Проблема повторилась на свежем тестовым приложении без каких-либо изменений в конфигурации приложения со стандартным контроллером и одним методом. Код теста прикладываю.

```
 public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        int worker = 0;
        int io = 0;
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out worker, out io);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

Под отладкой видно,что при двух запросах, приложение ждет выполнения первого запроса и только потом запускает второй.То есть по сути asp приложение вело себя как однопоточное приложение с блокировкой.Было замечено,что если отправлять запросы с разных браузеров, то блокировка не наблюдается. Поведение не постоянное. Вчера такое поведение наблюдалось в течении 2 часов на трех разных компьютерах. Сегодня периодически приложение ведет себя как и должно, периодически как однопоточное. Помогите разобраться с таким поведением,пожалуйста.

**UPD** Изначально проблема была замечена,когда долго выполняющийся запрос блокировал все приложение.

Comment: а если отправлять запросы из разных приложений? или кейс как раз в том, что одно приложение должно запросы делать параллельно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Браузер (по крайней мере [хром](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236124/google-chrome-queued-request-one-by-one-when-multiple-requests-to-a-localhost-no)) сам придерживает следующий get запрос на тот же url, и не отправляет его до получения ответа на предыдущий. Это достаточно легко проверяется любым отладчиком http, например, Fiddler.

---

На стороне ASP.NET запросы могут выстраиваться в очередь при использовании [Session State](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424111/177221). Полноценного решения без полного отказа от Session State нет, но последствия можно сгладить выборочным отключением Session State для отдельных действий.

Comment: Тогда как объяснить,что периодически программа и браузер ведут себя как ожидается от них изначально ? Как это можно контролировать ?

Comment: И что делать с долго выполняющимися запросами ? Понятно, что  можно добавить асинхронность, но это странно , т.к.  всегда думал, что asp приложение  изначально нам  неявно предоставляет асинхронность со своим пулом потоков.

Comment: @songof5ky asp.net предоставляет многопоточность (это совсем не то же самое, что асинхронность). Тут проблема не в asp.net, а в том, что браузер запрос вообще не присылает на сервер. Например, по ссылке из ответа у человека вообще nodejs на сервере, а проблема та же. Как бороть - или приписывать уникальные get-параметры (`?t=' + (new Date().getTime())`), или использовать POST.

Comment: Про асинхронность и многопоточность неправильно выразился, согласен.
Проблема была выявлена, когда долгоиграющий запрос блокировал другой запрос по другому адресу. Причем  это наблюдалось даже если второй запрос отправить с новой вкладки.
На самом деле только что разобрались в этой проблеме - вся ситуация возникла из-за использования сессий. Похоже на то, что когда выполнялась долгоиграющая операция в сессии, сессия блокировалась и ставила следующие запросы в очередь.

Comment: Вот тут можно почитать - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead

Comment: @songof5ky про сессии у меня есть ответ - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424111/177221 - просто чаще выстреливает блокировка get в бразуере, чем сессии. :)

Comment: Понял, спасибо, отличный ответ который разложил все по своим местам)